# How to minimize multivariate function in Matlab by using derivatives?

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, derivative

How to minimize multivariate function in Matlab by using derivatives?

So far, for minimizing single variable functions I used fminunc,
but now I need to work with multivariate functions.

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking about multiobjective optimiziation?

Comment: No, multivariable. I need to minimize a function for two variables. That is argmin.

Comment: `fminunc` should work then as long as your function returns a scalar.

Comment: Oh it works for multiple variables too. Good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`fminunc`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fminunc.html). If you want to use the gradient, just return it as the 2nd output of your objective function. You'll also need to indicate in an `options` object that you are passing the gradient.

```
options = optimoptions('fminunc','GradObj','on');
```

I believe the documentation has info on passing the Hessian (if one exists).

Comment: By the way, is there a book I can study on the various optimization stuff available in Matlab?

Comment: Sorry, I just go by the documentation on the Optimization toolbox!

Comment: There is a book "Applied Optimization with MATLAB Programming". I found it with a quick Google search. I would still go with the official documentation.